# Setstate for statless widget dropdownButton from a stateful parent

Tags: flutter, dart, state, setstate

I have three widgets first one is `LightBulb(stateless)` that have some color properties. The second one is widget named as `LightColorSelector(stateless)` that has a `DropdownMenu` with string type items `Red`, `Green`and `Blue`. And, the third class is `Classroom(stateful widget)` which is the parent of that two classes. My aim is to set the states from that class.
I need to set a list of that three colors inside the `Classroom`, when someone clicks on one of the `LightColorSelector` items the `LightBulb` should switches according to clicked color. However, the color inside the  `LightBulb` returns always null. I think it didn't set. Actually, I might know where is the mistake. I think in the `LightColorSelector` function there is a `onChanged` property and I didn't set the `value` into the `func()`. I marked below where I suspect the mnistake is occur.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class LightBulb extends StatelessWidget {
  bool isLit;
  Color color;
  LightBulb(bool isLit, Color color) {
    this.isLit = isLit;
    this.color = color;
    print(color.toString());
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: isLit ? color : Colors.red,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      child: isLit ? Text('ON') : Text('OFF'),
    );
  }
}

class LightButton extends StatelessWidget {
  Function func;
  bool isLightOn;
  LightButton(Function func, bool iSLightOn) {
    this.func = func;
    this.isLightOn = iSLightOn;
  }
  String title() {
    if (isLightOn) return "Turn light off";
    return "Turn light on";
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4, horizontal: 12),
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: MaterialButton(
          textColor: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () => func(),
          child: Text(
            title(),
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Classroom extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ClassroomState createState() => _ClassroomState();
}

class _ClassroomState extends State<Classroom> {
  bool isLightOn = false;
  String title = "Not set yet";
  List<Color> lightColor = [Colors.red, Colors.green, Colors.blue];
  Color color;
  String value;
  selectLightColor() {
    setState(() {
      if (value == 'Red') color = lightColor[0];
      if (value == 'Green') color = lightColor[1];
      if (value == 'Blue')
        color = lightColor[2];
      else
        color = Colors.amber;
    });
  }

  onButtonPressed() {
    setState(() {
      isLightOn = !isLightOn;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            LightBulb(isLightOn, color),
            LightButton(onButtonPressed, isLightOn),
            LightColorSelector(selectLightColor),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LightColorSelector extends StatelessWidget {
  String initialVal = 'Red';
  Function func;
  LightColorSelector(Function func) {
    this.func = func;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: DropdownButton(
          value: initialVal,
          onChanged: (value) => func, // =========== Here the error occurs ==========================
          items: <String>['Red', 'Green', 'Blue']
              .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ));
  }
}
```

Sample output,

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: Set initial value in `_ClassroomState`

```
class _ClassroomState extends State<Classroom> {
  ..
  Color color = Colors.red;
  String value = 'Red';
```

Step 2: Callback function `selectLightColor` need parameter `selectedValue` and use `if else if`, you have logic error here

```
selectLightColor(String selectedValue) {
    setState(() {
      value = selectedValue;
      if (selectedValue == 'Red') {
        color = lightColor[0];
      } else if (selectedValue == 'Green') {
        color = lightColor[1];
      } else if (selectedValue == 'Blue')
        color = lightColor[2];
      else
        color = Colors.amber;
    });
  }
```

Step 3: `LightColorSelector` `constructor` and `onChanged` need to set `initialVal` and `onChanged` need to call `func(value)`;

```
class LightColorSelector extends StatelessWidget {
  String initialVal;
  Function func;

  LightColorSelector(Function func, String value) {
    this.func = func;
    this.initialVal = value;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: DropdownButton<String>(
          value: initialVal,
          onChanged: (value) {
            initialVal = value;

            func(value);
          },
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(body: Classroom()),
    );
  }
}

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class LightBulb extends StatelessWidget {
  bool isLit;
  Color color;
  LightBulb(bool isLit, Color color) {
    this.isLit = isLit;
    this.color = color;
    print(color.toString());
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: isLit ? color : Colors.red,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      child: isLit ? Text('ON') : Text('OFF'),
    );
  }
}

class LightButton extends StatelessWidget {
  Function func;
  bool isLightOn;
  LightButton(Function func, bool iSLightOn) {
    this.func = func;
    this.isLightOn = iSLightOn;
  }
  String title() {
    if (isLightOn) return "Turn light off";
    return "Turn light on";
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4, horizontal: 12),
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: MaterialButton(
          textColor: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () => func(),
          child: Text(
            title(),
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Classroom extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ClassroomState createState() => _ClassroomState();
}

class _ClassroomState extends State<Classroom> {
  bool isLightOn = false;
  String title = "Not set yet";
  List<Color> lightColor = [Colors.red, Colors.green, Colors.blue];
  Color color = Colors.red;
  String value = 'Red';

  selectLightColor(String selectedValue) {
    setState(() {
      value = selectedValue;
      if (selectedValue == 'Red') {
        color = lightColor[0];
      } else if (selectedValue == 'Green') {
        color = lightColor[1];
      } else if (selectedValue == 'Blue')
        color = lightColor[2];
      else
        color = Colors.amber;
    });
  }

  onButtonPressed() {
    setState(() {
      isLightOn = !isLightOn;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        //color: Colors.blue,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            LightBulb(isLightOn, color),
            LightButton(onButtonPressed, isLightOn),
            LightColorSelector(selectLightColor, value),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LightColorSelector extends StatelessWidget {
  String initialVal;
  Function func;

  LightColorSelector(Function func, String value) {
    this.func = func;
    this.initialVal = value;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: DropdownButton<String>(
          value: initialVal,
          onChanged: (value) {
            initialVal = value;

            func(value);
          },
          items: <String>['Red', 'Green', 'Blue']
              .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

StatelessWidget doesn't have a state so you can't set state in stateless widget, this is why it called stateless. If you want to set state you need to use stateful widget

Comment: I am not setting a state inside the `stateless widget`. I am trying to pass a parameter to the `stateless widget's constructor` and via that parameter inserting a `state` from a parent `stateful widget`. Please read the instructions carefully.

Comment: oh i see, my bad. I'm not sure about your question but using methods which is returns Widgets would be better than using classes which is extends stateless widget Because you can easily access Stateful widgets variables in this case. And you can do setState on this methods also@Demir

Comment: @Demir im not sure but probably the problem is you're using func instead of func() in LightColorSelector onChanged method. Check it maybe will work for you